# virtualbox client machine: host name lookup failure in telnet while the same hostname lookup success in ping

Tags: networking, centos, virtualbox

I setup a virtualbox client machine which runs centos6.2 64bit, the host machine is windows7 64bit, and setup two net cards in the client machine, first is NAT mode, second is host-only mode, then I fall into the following problem while running the client centos:

when I ping mirror.centos.org, it seems reached the name:

```
PING mirror.centos.org (202.76.233.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 202.76.233.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=91.2 ms
```

when I telnet the same hostname, it failed:

```
$ telnet mirror.centos.org 80
telnet: mirror.centos.org: Name or service not known
mirror.centos.org: Host name lookup failure
```

but when I telnet the ip directly, it success:

```
$ telnet 202.76.233.2 80
Trying 202.76.233.2...
Connected to 202.76.233.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

my question is: when ping success, the host name seems been resolved, why it lookup failure again when telnet the same host name?
(actually it also fail to resolve the same host name in other program such as yum)

Thanks for any help.

append describe:

Sorry, I have a mistake to describe the problem, the manully dns is disable by the router, so it seems the problem happen in centos again. 
I use tcpdump to capture the dns package when running "telnet www.centos.org 80", the log list here:

```
16:12:15.662796 IP 192.168.116.129.54451 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 19272+ A? www.centos.org. (32)
16:12:15.662914 IP 192.168.116.129.54451 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 33092+ AAAA? www.centos.org. (32)
16:12:15.665205 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.54451: 19272 1/0/0 A 85.12.30.227 (48)
16:12:15.667042 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.54451: 33092- 0/0/0 (43)
16:12:15.667121 IP 192.168.116.129.47706 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 19272+ A? www.centos.org. (32)
16:12:15.667226 IP 192.168.116.129.47706 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 33092+ AAAA? www.centos.org. (32)
16:12:15.667977 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.47706: 19272 1/0/0 A 85.12.30.227 (48)
16:12:15.670181 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.47706: 33092- 0/0/0 (43)
16:12:15.670291 IP 192.168.116.129.34270 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 61846+ A? www.centos.org.localdomain. (44)
16:12:15.670393 IP 192.168.116.129.34270 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 7936+ AAAA? www.centos.org.localdomain. (44)
16:12:15.671208 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.34270: 61846 NXDomain*- 0/0/0 (44)
16:12:15.673649 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.34270: 7936- 0/0/0 (55)
16:12:15.673726 IP 192.168.116.129.49484 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 61846+ A? www.centos.org.localdomain. (44)
16:12:15.673827 IP 192.168.116.129.49484 > 192.168.116.2.domain: 7936+ AAAA? www.centos.org.localdomain. (44)
16:12:15.674595 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.49484: 61846 NXDomain*- 0/0/0 (44)
16:12:15.676653 IP 192.168.116.2.domain > 192.168.116.129.49484: 7936- 0/0/0 (55)
```

in the 3th line, the dns server had returned the address which queried, but the "telnet" continue querying, and later it put a tail to the domain(www.centos.org.localdomain), it's ofcourse a wrong host name, so why this happend?

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and trace the failed lookup.  2) Check out these Redhat bugs: [Bug 504951](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=504951), [Bug 508481](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=508481) and [Bug 442047](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=442047).

Comment: Q: Why does "ping" work but "telnet" fail for the same host?  A: (suggested by Redhat bugs cited above): maybe the telnet client is pulling in different NSS libraries.  ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION: Also consider installing a different  "telnet" client.  Make sure the new client is 64-bit (no 32-bit dependencies).

Comment: thanks for advice. I had make sure the telnet is x86-64, 64bit client.

Comment: Glad you got the problem resolved :)

Comment: I have check the Bug list above, the centos has no yum package like nss-mdns, so it seems not affect centos. Finally, I found when I use manually DNS for the NAT mode net card of client os(centos), the dns do not work even when ping, the same manully dns work in my host machine, it's strange, and seams that the problem is in virtualbox, I am not familiar with it's network. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The log file might be helpful, there're three name-resolution modes in VirtualBox, "NATing" UDP requests, proxying (when DNS requests're forwarded to the list of host's DNS servers) and host resolving (when NAT uses hosts name resolving API to reply on DNS requests) - so log could point what is the case. if you open copy & paste output of at least `tcpdump "port domain"` in other terminal  here.